# How can I embed text labels for hardcoded values in Excel Lambda expressions?

Tags: excel, lambda

I'm great with Excel and VBA, but about to help convert someone else's workbook into something more usable, eliminating VBA (UDFs) and cleaning up named ranges. New to Lambda formulas/named ranges, but it seems like a good solution here.

With Lambda, is there any way to include a text descriptor along with a hardcoded value inside the Lambda? The intent is to provide future users with a clearer understanding of what is going on inside the Lambda (what different values represent)

I suspect one way would be to use the formula +n("text") trick, but I wanted to ask first in case there is a better way already designed into the Lambda syntax.

For the sake of example, let's use a common formula like circumference of a circle, 2*Pi*R. I get R as the Lambda user input, and I hardcopy 3.14 for Pi. I want to include a *label* so the reader knows that the 3.14 is specifically Pi in this Lambda formula, but not require the user to provide that value each time the Lambda is used, it stays hardcoded.

(the real UDFs I'm converting are more complex and have a number of hardcoded variables I need to include)

Note: I know I could hardcode values as a separate 'name', then put that name in the Lambda - but I'd much prefer to have the names and the values all be embedded in the same Lambda. Also, this workbook already has an excess of names and my goal is already to get rid of as many as possible, not add more.

Thank you!

Comment: no.  the `+n(text)` trick basically the only way.  You can name your variables in a manner that make it obvious, but other than that, no

Answer (score 0):

You can make a lambda with no arguments that just returns 3.14 and name it pi in the name manager

you can test it with `=LAMBDA(3.14)()` in any cell, will return 3.14